# Objective-C - Is there a way to "override" dot syntax?

Tags: objective-c

Take for example the following:

```
Project *project = [[Project alloc] init];
project.title = @"MyProject";
project.field = @"SomeOtherField";
```

I want to set a flag whenever a property is changed. Is there any way this can be done when the property changed is done via dot syntax?

I *could* just overwrite

```
- (void) setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
```

And set the object properties using KVC:

```
[project setValue:@"SomeOtherField" forKey:@"field"];
```

But the dot syntax always looks cleaner ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Key-Value Observing`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) if you will be doing this with more than one property/object.

Register as an observer:

```
[project addObserver:self
          forKeyPath:@"title"
             options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOldKey)
             context:NULL];
```

Implement the change handler

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
   if ([object isKindOfClass:[Project class]] && [keyPath isEqual:@"title"]) {
       //do something with [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
   }

   [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                        ofObject:object
                          change:change
                         context:context];
}
```

Comment: Learned something new. Thnks.

Answer (score 2):

The dot syntax obj.var=x is converted to [obj setVar:x]. So to override the dot is achieved creating the method 
-(void) setVar:...

I do it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When using properties, you could have `setTitle` and it work with `project.title`.

```
- (void) setTitle:(NSString *)title;
```